# Anguluar material date-picker overlay dissapears behind card-content or is just cut off?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, frontend

I creating a web-page to display Angular Material form input styles. I have several already listed that work fine but then date-picker seems to display incorrectly no matter how/where I arrange it. I click the calendar icon button, the calendar pops up, but then is cut-off.

Angular ver: 15.0.4
Angular-mat ver: 15.0.3

[cut off mat-calendar pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7EXV.png)

I've attempted to:

1. Display it at the top if the lists of inputs
2. Display it outside of the whole mat-card div and mat-card-content div, it still behaves the same way
3. Restarted my server

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.